# Machine Learning outcome with more than 2 categories-caret

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification

I know that there are many algorithms for ML problems where the outcome has 2 categories.
I am wondering kwon if there are algorithms that accept outcomes with more than 2 categories, especially in the caret package.

Answer (score 0):

For categorical features one of best algorithm is catboost , I am not sure if you are looking for regression or classification . But I hope this helps

https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/r-quickstart

Comment: The question considers categorical outcomes, not categorical features.

Answer (score 0):

Every model for binary outcomes that I know has a multiclass analogue.

Logistic regression has multinomial logistic regression.

Neural networks with sigmoid activation functions for the final layer have softmax activation for multiple output neurons.

Random forest handles $3+$ classes fine. SVM handles $3+$ classes fine.

Depending on the software, there might be considerable differences when it comes to preprocessing data and calling functions, but it can be done.